# What is this scenery object in Pokemon Red Version?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

[image]

This is a screenshot from Pokemon Red version.

Number 1 looks like a tree (I originally thought it was a rock until recently).  What is number 2 though?

Comment: +1 for asking something I've always wondered but never had a place to ask

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1 is a shrub. An impassible shrub that is used as a barrier for forests as opposed to those weird circle blocks on the right (2) which are used for cities/built up areas. I don't really think 2 is based on anything in real life, it's just there to impede progress and look kind of like it belongs around buildings.

Comment: If I can't get a solid answer in the next little while, you will be the answer.  Sorry, I just am hoping for some kind of exact answer or explanation.  :)

Comment: It does resemble a cycle bollard. http://i.imgur.com/iH7hz.jpg

Comment: @Jonathan Very true!  It does appear as if they are linked kind of though.  +1 for a good point though!

Answer (score 7):

I believe that is fencing, from my knowledge of the old games anyway. If I can, I will fire up the game and take a look to confirm it.

Answer (score 5):

this is what they are:

[image: Cement barriers]

however they are much bigger than in this picture. I've seen the big ones in real life we have them at my local bus station for safety in case the brakes on a bus stop working they are big and strong enough to stop a bus and so, in the game they cant be penetrated by you or your Pokemon